# Select and calculate a column

Tags: mysql, string, select, integer

I have my table named calculate_genmat:

```
genmat_id     mat_name   size      req_qty   stock_released    
1             flat bar   100 m      350            4
```

How can I select my table with the formula (size * stock_released) - req_qty to reject column?
Convert the size column into integer only value so it can be multiplied to stock_released and soon. Then the reject output should have back the meter label taken from the size column.

```
100 * 4 = 400
400 - 350 = 50
reject = 50 m
```

like:

```
genmat_id     mat_name   size      req_qty   stock_released   reject 
1             flat bar   100 m      350            4           50 m
```

Comment: If you must store units, store them separate from values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try easily this

```
SELECT
   *, CONCAT(size  * stock_released - req_qty ,' m')  as reject
FROM calculate_genmat
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd0d8/3)